# Save toJSON and load Kinetic.Layer by keeping the same events that I defined and images

Tags: json, kineticjs

Is there a concrete example about saving layers that contain images + shapes + events on each node to JSON format, and then load it? What I have done until now is saving to JSON.

I want to give the user the ability to save what he has done, close his computer (his session on the website), then when he connects again, the old saved layers appear. So he can continue drawing, dragging and dropping, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can only save shapes and its attributes to JSON. You can't save images and events.

After loading stage from JSON, you will have to reassign all the images again as well as the events.

Here's a tutotial from KineticJS website regarding [Complex Stage Loading](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-load-complex-stage-with-kineticjs/)

Edit1: I had the same problem you're having... In order to solve this, after loading the stage, layers and shapes, I just get the shapes I want to assign events by using `find` on its `name` attribute. You may also consider using `find` by `type` for the same purpose.

Comment: This part of kineticJS could have been simpler, in large applications it's hard to locate things.. Thank you :)

Comment: I wish they made more examples and tutorials on this subject